# What versions of Python packages are supported in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying out Google Cloud Functions for the first time, and I am using the Python 3.7 runtime. I would like to install package PyYAML so I added this to requirements.txt

`PyYAML==3.12`

Deployment failed with error:

> Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:\n  Failed building wheel for pyyaml\nERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels\n\nerror: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "44FA08B0"}}

That error isn't very helpful. Through trial and error I discovered that if I remove the "==3.12" stipulation:

`PyYAML`

then the deployment succeeds.

I'm interested to know:
* Is there a stated policy of which versions of packages are supported in Google Cloud Functions?
* How can i discover which versions of a particular package (PyYAML in this case) are supported in Google Cloud Functions?

(I'm using 3.12 because that's what a solution that we have internally is using - I can use a later version, and will do so, but I'm interested in answers to the above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this could be a problem related to GCF. Usually, it should be a problem with Python3.7.

> 3.13 (2018-07-05)
>
> Rebuild wheels using latest Cython for Python 3.7 support.

As you can see the change log of `PyYAML`. I think it just doesn't support Python 3.7 before `3.13` version.